# Real Business Cycle Theory

Tags: macroeconomics, labor-economics, real-business-cycles

Which academic paper does this diagram come from? Need to know for citation purposes. Apparently its King and Rebelo (2005) but doesn't seem to be the case.
[image]

Comment: Where did you find the diagram? What else can you say about it, e.g. which country's data are we looking at? This is precious little to go on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's from King and Rebelo (2000) "Resuscitating Real Business Cycles". Here is a [link to the NBER working paper version](http://www.nber.org/papers/w7534.pdf). The graph is in Figure 8 on p.94.